# Connection pooling vs persistent connection in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have a web server running `ASP.NET`. An `SQL Server` database is frequently queried for data. For all queries, a connection is opened and then closed as shown below.

Is this considered good practice? For a web server? Why?

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))  
{  
    SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();  

    command.CommandText = "my_stored_proc";
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;  

    connection.Open();  

    return command.ExecuteScalar();  
}
```

Comment: That is the one and only BEST practice. Connection pooling makes reopening a connection very cheap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your website is accessed by very few users then using any of these two options will not show any difference. But when there are 1000's of users accessing your website then creating a persistent connection will create 1000's of connections on server that will effect performance of the server and also memory resources on server will be wasted and hence in this case connection pooling is recommended i.e what you did in your code.